# Saving file to resource directory using Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have this project structure:

```
/webapp
  /res
    /img
      /profile.jpg
  /WEB-INF
```

And I need to save file to `res/img/` directory. This time I have this code:

```
public String fileUpload(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        File newFile = new File("/res/img/" + fileName);

        try {
            inputStream = file.getInputStream();

            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                newFile.createNewFile();
            }
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

But it saving files to `user.dir` directory, which is `~/Work/Tomcat/bin/`.
So how I can upload files to `res` directory?

Comment: Don't upload files there. Choose a separate directory dedicated to that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why the `res` directory doesn't appropriate?

Comment: For one, because it doesn't necessarily exist. The `Servlet` container might choose not to expand your `.war`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for your answer. Can you please write what is the best practice to upload and save some user content(like avatars, docs, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: what is UploadedFile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't really be uploading files there.

If you are using a war, redeploying will delete them. If they are intended to be temporary then use an os assigned temporary location.

If you intend to publish them afterwards then choose a location in which to store the files on your server, make this location known to the application and save and load files from the location.

If you are trying to replace resources dynamically such as an image which is referenced in the html or css templates, then consider publishing the external location separately, you can use mvc:resources for this e.g:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:/absolute/path/to/image/dir"/>
```

and you would save your files to that location. This will make it more permanent between deployments.

To save an image to that location using your code you will need to add this into your bean definition (assuming you are using xml configuration without annotations):

```
<property name="imagesFolder" value="/absolute/path/to/image/dir"/>
```

and keeping your code as similar as possible change it to:

```
private String imagesFolder;
public void setImagesFolder(String imagesFolder) {
    this.imagesFolder = imagesFolder;
}
public String fileUpload(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    File newFile = new File(imagesFolder + fileName);

    try {
        inputStream = file.getInputStream();

        if (!newFile.exists()) {
            newFile.createNewFile();
        }
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Please bear in mind that you need to change /absolute/path/to/image/dir to an actual path that exists, also I would recommend to look at the [Spring Resources documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources) for a better way to deal with files and resources.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please tell me, how I can call `/absolute/path/..` in my code to store there data?`

Comment: I meant another.
Is there an opportunity to receive this address in the controller with a method call? Or I need to write this path always oneself?

Comment: what are you talking about? Putting files on your project's (not tomcat) webapp folder is not the same as what you are talking about here. Completely off point

Answer (score 4):

Please refer FileUploadController from  [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files)  to save file to the specified directory.

```
public String fileUpload(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();

    String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "webapp"+File.separator+"res"+File.separator+"img");
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName);

    try {
        inputStream = file.getInputStream();

        if (!newFile.exists()) {
            newFile.createNewFile();
        }
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```