# SpringMVC file uploads are not seen before server update

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, file-upload

I am using SpringMVC and TomCat server. I am developing an app, in which you can upload files. Everything is fine, the files are being updated, but when I try to reach them, it returns 404. When I update the resources through the compiler (IntelliJ IDEA if it matters), the new files are now reachable and accessible. The thing is that every file is uploaded into a different directory which is calculated (/uploads/table_name/row_id/File.txt for example).

Now I am storing the files inside the project( src/main/webapp/uploads/the other directories). I am using the commons-fileupload. I don't know what code should be relevant to show, or if I explained the problem properly enough. If anyone has suggestions I will be very grateful.

Comment: You are storing the files inside the running project directory structure..tomcat will not know about the files untill next restart.. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063140/saving-file-to-resource-directory-using-spring

Comment: You should be saving your files to outside your project directory.It will be removed on next deployment of your project if those are in your project

Comment: Thank you for the help. This really helped me and I fixed the problem.